# Hide a div based on select radio button in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

I have a form where you have to choose between two `input type="radio"`, one says **yes** and the other one says **no**.
I want to make a div that is visible in the form disappear when you select the **no** option. I tried by copying some JS from other posts I read on the internet, but nothing worked for me.
Can someone tell me the code I should use? It can be JS, PHP or CSS.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="form-radio">
<label for="sons" class="radio-label">Question:</label>
<div class="form-radio-item">
<input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" checked value="YES">
<label for="hsi">YES</label>
<span class="check"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-radio-item">
<input type="radio" name="no" id="no" value="NO">
<label for="hno">NO</label>
<span class="check"></span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="hello">
You clicked on NO, so this div disappears.    
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried to make it work? You mention you have tried some code but it doesn't seem to be in your post.

Comment: Your radio buttons don't even function as radio buttons (when you click one, the other remains selected) - because they have different `name` attributes.

Comment: @RobinZigmond so you say that first, I should change the `name`of the inputs so they have the same?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Do not ask such questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yes that's what Robin means

Answer (score 1):

You need to add event listeners to your inputs, as well you should change the name of both radio buttons to be the same thing. I used `inputs` below. I then toggle the `display` style on the `#hello` element depending on which selection was clicked.

```js
const hello = document.getElementById('hello');

document.getElementById('yes')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    hello.style.display = null;
  });
  
document.getElementById('no')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    hello.style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-radio">
<label for="sons" class="radio-label">Question:</label>
<div class="form-radio-item">
<input type="radio" name="inputs" id="yes" checked value="YES">
<label for="hsi">YES</label>
<span class="check"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-radio-item">
<input type="radio" name="inputs" id="no" value="NO">
<label for="hno">NO</label>
<span class="check"></span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="hello">
You clicked on NO, so this div disappears.    
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Do not answer such off topic questions. The question will be deleted eventually.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it does not work. Maybe is because I have another inputs in my form?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with pure CSS. Don't know if my solution is suitable because I have no idea how the rest of your page is structured.

```css
.form-radio {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

input#no ~ #floatingDescription  {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
}

input#no:checked ~ #floatingDescription {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hml>

<body>
  <div class="form-radio">
    <label for="sons" class="radio-label">Question:</label>
    <div class="form-radio-item">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" id="yes" checked>
      <label for="hsi">YES</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-radio-item">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" id="no">
      <label for="hno">NO</label>
      <div id="floatingDescription">You clicked on NO, so this div disappears.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```